# JQuery $.each (VS) Javascript forEach, performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

In term of performances
when parsing a large file (JSon file e.g.),

which loop process is the quicker ?

$.each (jquery) or foreach (javascript) ?

Answer (score 4):

Performance wise they are very equal:
[Performance test](https://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-js-foreach/10)

You could say that `forEach` has the benefit of being *"native"*. Which makes it easier to maintain for developers with little `jquery` knowledge. Then again $.each is not that hard to read.

I would say choose as you like.

**Edit:** I assumed you were using Jquery. It could of course be any library that implements an each function.